# .htaccess 301 redirects for XAMPP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I've spent enough hours on this problem and have had no success, so it's time to ask.

The specific part of the problem I'm on now is redirecting non-WWW URLs to WWW URLs. There's many resources on doing this, and none have worked properly.

I currently have the following, with nothing else in the file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've also tried many variations of this, including ones with hard-coded URLs.

Here is what happens on various browsers across XAMPP and the live version.

```
XAMPP, Firefox. "example.com" -> "http://www.example.com/"
XAMPP, Chrome. "example.com" -> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
XAMPP, Edge. "example.com" -> Hmm, we can't reach this page. 

Live, Firefox. "example.com" -> "http://www.example.com/"
Live, Chrome. "example.com" -> "http://www.example.com/"
Live, Edge. "example.com" -> "http://www.example.com/"
```

(Live, Edge, was not working when I started this post, but I forgot to clear the cache. I'm still interested in getting it all working with XAMPP though.)

This is with the 301 redirect cache disabled. A virtual host is set for XAMPP to map example.com to htdocs/example. example.com is mapped to localhost in the hosts file.

How can I get these inputs to work for a XAMPP hosted server too? Any solutions need to be compatible with having clean URLs, trailing slashes, truncated slashes, and removed .php extensions.

Who made web development so hard...

Comment: This sounds like a DNS / cache problem. There is nothing wrong with the .htaccess code you have posted, particularly if this is working for some environments and not others. When connected to the local (XAMPP) server, are you connected to the internet? If you have `example.com` defined in HOSTS then you will also need `www.example.com` defined in HOSTS as well, otherwise it will redirect to the live site (if it resolves at all).  Your VirtualHost also needs to be able to accept requests to `www.example.com`, not just `example.com`.

Comment: Excellent, that did it. I added the host entry, and then an equal virtual host entry, and it's working fine. Well that's a load of stress gone, thank you very much. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would seem to be a DNS related problem.

> A virtual host is set for XAMPP to map example.com to htdocs/example. example.com is mapped to localhost in the hosts file.

If you have `example.com` defined in your HOSTS file then you will also need `www.example.com` defined in HOSTS as well, otherwise it will redirect to the live site (if it resolves at all) which is where `www.example.com` points to.

Your local VirtualHost will also need to be able to accept requests to `www.example.com`, not just `example.com`. If using name-based virtual hosts then you can use `ServerAlias`, for example:

```
ServerAlias www.example.com
```